# How to send the user to a particular view controller upon tapping the notification?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification

I using the below function to perform the action upon tapping the notificaion ,but I am not able to get the right code to send the user to a particular view controller?
what should be the exact code to send user to the particular view controller upon tapping the notification? I am a newbie to swift, please help me

```
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
                print(response)
                let application = UIApplication.shared

                if(application.applicationState == .active){
                    print("user tapped the notification bar when the app is in foreground")


                }

                if(application.applicationState == .inactive)
                {
                    print("user tapped the notification bar when the app is in background")
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
             let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "notificationcenter") as? NotificationsListViewController
             self.window?.rootViewController = vc

                }


                completionHandler()
            }
```

Comment: Your code bears little relation to the question.  You ask for for help deciding which VC to send to but provide no information how you want to make that decision or the view controllers you want to access.  Consider revising your question.

Comment: @flanker Hey, I have edited the code and added the viewcontroller to I want the action to happen, will this work?